# Metamask RPC error -32603... {"error":"revert","program_counter":6758,"return":"0x"}

Tags: truffle, metamask, erc-721, truffle-test

I have a dApp that leverages ERC721 contract which allows users to upload images onto IPFS and transfer them to each other.
User A can upload images fine and transfer them fine to User B. Once transferred User A can still upload new images -perfect! However, when User B then logins onto Metamask and try's to upload sketch's(string value of hash) I am hit with the error message below.

`MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert","code":-32000,"data":{"0x33acf11f7fb6df195a58a8cd8e21a0f837f2710540f19122548f625ba5a5aef6":{"error":"revert","program_counter":6758,"return":"0x"},"stack":"c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.c.fromResults (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:4:194812)\n    at w.processBlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:42:53376)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)","name":"c"}}}}'`

I have a truffle test which passes when a user uploads, transfers and then uploads again. Do I need a truffle test for a different account accessing and uploading sketch's to expose this problem? If so how do you change the accounts address accessing the contract in truffle test environment?
I begin the truffle test.js and expose the contract as follows:

```
const Sketch = artifacts.require('./Sketch.sol')

require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should()

contract('Sketch', (accounts) => {
    let contract

    before(async () => {
        contract = await Sketch.deployed()
    })

    describe('deployment', async () => {
        it('deploys successfully', async () => {
            const address = contract.address
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
            assert.notEqual(address, '')
            assert.notEqual(address, null)
            assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
        })
```

Any help would be great

Comment: You can send a transaction from another account in truffle by appending `{ from: "0x12341234.." }`. So it will look like `myContract.myFunc(myParam1, myParam2, { from: '0xabcdefabcdef...'} )`.